# In Azure mobile apps where is the local database stored?

Tags: sqlite, azure, mobile

Azure mobile apps provide the advantage over standard web apps that users can work offline (eg if offsite in an area with no or poor Wifi or other internet access). Data is stored in a local database which is kept in sync with the backend database stored in Azure.

Where is the local database stored?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer (for a Windows 8.1 client - answers will be different for other clients, eg Android, iOS/iPhone/Windows Phone).

For a Windows 8.1 client, the local database ("localstore.db") is stored somewhere in AppData/Local (my thanks to https://disqus.com/by/adrianhall/ for this information).

A search for localstore.db in AppData/Local showed in my case that it is located (on my Windows 10 pc) in:

C:\Users[myname]\AppData\Local\Packages\d0464449-5b1d-400f-94f5-898e44186049_yps17xarsp2at\LocalState\